# How can I run KazMan?

Tags: lxterminal

I have downloaded a screen recorder called Kazman. I can't find a way to run it or start the program. I have tried typing in `kazman` in LXTerminal and got this response:

> bash: kazman: command not found

If you would like to install it the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install kazman
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: I have to go to school now so i will not be able to reply to answers i will be back at about 3:30.

Comment: Have you tried what it said: sudo apt-get install kazman?

Comment: I didn't find application called `kazman` to screen recording. I found `kazam` and it was [Ubuntu package](https://launchpad.net/~kazam-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable-series). Can you tell us what OS you got?

Answer (score 0):

The right name of the package is kazam. Have You tried accessing the binary with the full path?

Maybe Your $PATH variable doesn't contain the default paths? echo $PATH should give something like:

```
[root@server ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

If it's empty, or the required path is not here, you may set the PATH variable with this command

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
```

This command puts the usual default paths for binaries on your PATH variable which is used to locate commands to launcho in the OS from anywhere.

Not sure about your O.S. In Debian, the default full path for kazam usually is `/usr/bin/kazam`

Hope it helps.